# Apk install on sdk lesser than minSdkVersion specified in manifest

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, apk

I have an apk and I specifies API level 16 as my minSDKVersion in the manifest.
But when I see Play statistics, I see some installs on ICS(API level 15) and on GingerBread(API level 9).I am NOT sure how people are able to install my app in API level < 16
Has anyone faced this problem before? 
Will appreciate if you can share your experiences.

Best Regards,
Manan

Comment: Can you post your exact manifest file please?

Comment: Did a previous version of the app specify a lower minSDKVersion?